# Implementing Dijkstra's algorithm using CUDA in c

Tags: cuda, dijkstra

I am trying to implement Dijsktra's algorithm using cuda.I got a code that does the same using map reduce this is the link http://famousphil.com/blog/2011/06/a-hadoop-mapreduce-solution-to-dijkstra%E2%80%99s-algorithm/ but i want to implement something similar as given in the link using cuda using shared and global memory..Please tell me how to proceed as i am new to cuda ..i dont know if it is necessary that i provide the input on host and device both in the form of matrix and also what operation should i perform in the kernel function

Comment: This isn't really a question for stackoverflow. BUT, I start by doing something simpler to understand the fundamentals of cuda, and then move on to graph algorithms. I would also add that graph-algorithms often require some "trick" to be efficiently implemented using SIMD architectures.

Comment: Also, apparently this exists : http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/CUDA%20On%20Hadoop

Comment: actually i have implemented LU decomposition using cuda but i am not sure as to how i go about implementing Dijkstra..

Comment: Ohh, excellent :) LU descompression nice BLAS math, and exactly what cuda is made for. the problem with doing something like Dijkstra is that the random access part of the problem, if there is a trivial way of converting ddijkstra into a linear algebra problem I think you will be home free, if not I this its gonna be a failure.... this seems fun, please keep me posted :)

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this(Dislaimer this is not a map-reduce solution).

Lets say you have a Graph `G` with `N` states an adjacency matrix `A` with entries A[i,j] for the cost of going from node i to node j in the graph.

This Dijkstras algorithm consists of having a vector denoting a front 'V' where V[i] is the current minimum distance from the origin to node i - in Dijkstras algorithm this information would be stored in a heap and loaded poped of the top of the heap on every loop.

Running the algorithm now starts to look a lot like matrix algebra in that one simply takes the Vector and applyes the adjancicy matrix to it using the following command:

```
V[i] <- min{V[j] + A[j,i] | j in Nodes}
```

for all values of i in V. This is run as long as there are updates to V (can be checked on the device, no need to load V back and forth to check!), also store the transposed version of the adjacency matrix to allow sequential reads.

At most this will have a running time corresponding to the longest non-looping path through the graph.

The interesting question now becomes how to distribute this across compute blocks, but it seems obvious to shard based on row indexes.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you study these two prominent papers on *efficient graph processing on GPU*. First can be found [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.220.1923&rep=rep1&type=pdf). It's rather straightforward and basically assigns one warp to process a vertex and its neighbors. You can find the second one [here](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~pingali/CS395T/2013fa/papers/garlandGPU.pdf) which is more complicated. It efficiently produces the queue of next level vertices in parallel hence diminishing load imbalance.

After studying above articles, you'll have a better understanding why graph processing is challenging and where pitfalls are. Then you can make your own CUDA program.